# Sequence stores according to their distances using pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

i have 3 dataframes.

1.Contains distances of stores from the main warehouse.(df1)

```
ware_house    store   km
   1          1023    1.1
   1          1056    0.3
   1          1089    1.7
```

2.Contains distances of stores to store.(df2)

```
start_store    destination_store     km
   1023             1056             5.3
   1023             1089             3.7
   1056             1089             4.5
   1056             1023             5.8
   1089             1056             3.9
   1089             1023             4.2
```

i have 1 more dataframe which contains my test file (df3)

```
rowid    store    sequence
 100      1023
 101      1056
 102      1089
```

i want to sequence stores in df3 such that,

first it picks the store with minimum distance from warehouse and assign it sequence no. 1 in df3.

Then it looks for combination of that store with another stores and picks the least distance store and inserts sequence no.2 in my df3.

Similarly it checks for the next store with the same above logic.

In this case from **df1** we see that store 1056 has least km.

Therefore in **df3**, for **store 1056** assign sequence **1**

Then from df2 look for combination of other stores with **store 1056**
and select the least distance store, which in this case is **store 1089** and assign it sequence **2 in df3** . Similarly then look for combination of store 1089 with other store and generate next sequence.

my final df look like:

```
rowid    store    sequence
 100      1023      3
 101      1056      1
 102      1089      2
```

Note:This is just test example. i have to calculate for many stores.
Any help?

Comment: Better to look into the traveling salesmen problem (TSP) or the vehicle routing problem (VRP) because this is a combinatorial optimization problem, if you have more combinations than stated here, it will take a long time

Comment: @djk47463 many stores as in around 30-40

Comment: Well if you have 40 stores and one warehouse, the number of possible routes are (41-1)!/2, which is a huge number...

Comment: Is df1 and df3 of equal length?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no, they are of different lengths